# Is it okay to ask for feedback after an interview

Tags: interviewing, feedback

I recently went through the process of a phone interview, a personality test, and then a skills assessment test. All of these are common, I know and understand. My question is, is it reasonable, when a company lets you know that they are moving on without you, to ask for feedback on the last stage of the process? In my case, I'd like to know where I failed in the skills assessment, so that I might continue to learn and get better.

Comment: @enderland: I read that question and the suggested answer, but it's not really an answer to my question. In the one you linked, he asked but never heard back. I'm asking is it considered okay to ask to begin with.

Comment: [This answer](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/664/2322), [this one](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/711/2322), [this one](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/719/2322), [this one](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/744/2322), [this one](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/749/2322), and the [accepted answer](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/708/2322) all address this question.

Comment: @user9205 - Yes or no questions do not really fit this style of Q&A.  We prefer questions that ask "How can I understand?" over "What is the answer?"  You should be able to read the answers to that question and have an answer for your question.