# How much should I insist on a job?

Tags: interviewing, software-industry, human-resources, feedback

I would love to have a certain job in another company, they did the initial phone interview and then nothing happened from there.

I think I'm not very good at interviews, not because I get too nervous or anything, but it's more about trying too hard.  When I was interviewed, I also wanted out badly from where I was.  And I believe I blew it.

1. I would really like to have feedback from that time.  I want to know what am I missing to be the ideal candidate for them
2. They keep on posting the position.  Is this a red flag?  is this an opportunity that I should take advantage of?

Comment: Sorry to be brutal but how more red can the flag be? You interviewed for the position, did not get an offer, and the position is still open.

Comment: Given Blams' comment, the only part that's left to answer is 'How can I get feedback?' But that's trivial to answer: phone your contact(s).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I ask my interviewers for feedback following an interview?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/662/how-can-i-ask-my-interviewers-for-feedback-following-an-interview)

Comment: @Blam - it depends on the content of the phone interview (actual interview, or simple phone screening), and if the ad for the position was renewed beyond the original closing date, and if the employer has contacted all candidates for screening... i'd say this is an amber flag, as there are many reasons other than "you did not pass"

Answer (score 2):

1. While you could ask, there is a good chance the company isn't going to tell you the answer as what is in it for them to tell you how you blew it? I'd likely consider asking your network and possibly walking them through answers to see if they could pick out what you did that wasn't great.
2. This likely means you aren't passing the screen. While you could apply again, I would advise caution as it could be that more than a few are applying and the people that get the interview aren't doing well enough for the company to hire them. I have had positions where I applied for the job 5-6 times before finally physically handing my resume in at a career fair to get somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You may be over-analysing - while most companies should (and would) wait until a job ad is run-out before calling applicants, these guys might have jumped the gun a bit and now have to wait until all candidates have had a phone interview before continuing.

All you need to do right now is a short and polite email:

> Dear recruiter who conducted interview,
>
> Thank you for your time the other day. I was wondering if there has been any progress in considering my application for the position of whatever you applied for. I would appreciate any feedback you might have about how I conducted myself over the phone.
>
> Regards,
>   Youknowwho

This shows you are keen and motivated, and comes across as professional.