# Should I approach an interviewer before a decision has been made?

Tags: interviewing, new-job, email, linkedin

I am in a bit of a conundrum here.

I was interviewed in person by a panel of 5 interviewers(1 on 1, 5 hours back to back technical) **last Friday**. Today is the 4th day(Thursday here as I write this post).

As it happens that myself and all other people who are pursuing a Masters in CS course from my college are automatically enrolled in a mailing list where alumni working in different companies can post their job requirements and hire candidates directly from our college.

Yesterday (3rd day after my interview) I was just browsing the mailing list since I am in market for a new job and came across a certain mail which was posted by a guy who was one of the 5 interviewers I had interviewed with on Friday.**He  has posted a job position to be filled up, the same position for which I have been interviewed last Friday.**

**First Question :** Does this mean automatically I have been rejected , since they are looking for new candidates ? (I know it depends on the number of positions they want to be filled in)

**Second:** I found the particular interviewer's LinkedIn profile. Shall I send an in mail and ask him about my application status? Please note that during my entire process, the HR was the only POC. I have already  *[sent a mail to the HR yesterday](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/41630/i-followed-up-with-the-hr-regarding-my-onsite-interview-i-did-not-get-a-chance?noredirect=1#comment102679_41630)*(asking for a timeline, NOT a decision).

**Third :** I have a friend of mine who is working in the same company and happens to know the interviewer professionally and personally since they have both worked in the same team earlier. Shall I ask this friend of mine to indirectly ask the said interviewer about my decision? I know this is *rude*. I am not doing it. Just wanted to hear opinions from you guys.

Last, I haven't heard back from the HR as of today. Shall I just wait for next Monday(that completes 1 week) and reach back to the HR? or just move on...

Please help. ! This post might also help candidates who are in such a situation in future.!

Comment: They will continue to post until the position is filled.  It can take a while for things to clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So my take on this as a hiring manager:

A week is a short time in recruitment.  I know as a candidate, is seems like a HUGE wait, but as a hiring manager it can be nothing.

There could be a million reasons for the wait, for example:

- Maybe the hiring manager needs sign off from HR/his boss etc;
- Maybe a budget was expected to be signed off but hasn't yet
- Maybe someone in the team has resigned/been promoted and they are evaluating how this affects the hire.
- Maybe the advert got auto-renewed and reposted
- Sometimes adverts are bought in blocks and it's cheaper to repost a role even if it's about to close out
- Maybe they have another similar role coming up and knowing the market is hot want to get an early start on interest
- **You're also in college, I'm assuming the role is for once you finish, so their timeline may reflect the schedule for this**

I've had situations where a hire has spun out over weeks, however I do try an play fair with potential hires and keep them advised of what is happening (as much as I can), and let definite "No" candidates know as soon as possible, but the process may be HR driven, and they may not be so worried about nurturing the potential talent.

Usually the best way to move things on is another offer (or to make them become interested), best strategy is to view the job as a "No" until you hear otherwise.  **So keep pushing on with other opportunities while you wait, don't come to a stop waiting on a response on this one**.  Also don't start picturing yourself in the new job until an offer is in your hands.

You've emailed HR, but don't approach the interviewer, you may make the situation turn downwards by side-stepping the point of contact.  You should also prepare for the fact that maybe no news IS NEWS, far too many companies/recruiters do this and it's crappy, but it happens even at my level (I was approached by a company, had multiple interviews/tests over 6 weeks, flown to head office for final meet, then silence.  It's crappy but IT WILL HAPPEN so thicken your hide in prep).

The friend route could work, but they need to be discrete, and better to sound like THEY are asking, not approaching on your behalf.  The friend needs to be prepared as they may need to give you bad news though, so it might be better to wait.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am actually still waiting to hear from them and might send off another mail next week Tuesday/Wednesday. Actually I have already graduated, so a bit in a hurry .!

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by Blam in the comments, a posting about the same position can mean very little. There are any number of reasons to keep posting: They may be advertising the same position until they've made a decision. They might post after the fact, just to collect résumés, etc.

Do not approach the person on LinkedIn (or any other unofficial channel). The interviewer might just be someone who makes a recommendation based on the interview. They might not actually know the status of your application. And even if they did, approaching them outside the approved method of communication can have a negative impact on your chances. They *will* let you know, if you get the job.

That said, having your friend prod them a bit might be an OK idea. Their recommendation might carry some weight, even if it's just a "Hey! Heard you were considering peepee for the position. I think he'd fit right in." This has a very large number of caveats, though. As you mentioned, it's rude. It's effectiveness also depends on their position within the company, whether it's related to your potential position, the size of the company etc.

Comment: Thanks Celos. Yup I don't want to jeopardise my chances by contacting any of them via LinkedIn.Also, the friend of mine got to know that their company is actually hiring a large number of candidates for the particular position across various teams. He also told that had I been rejected already, the HR would have replied me back saying its a negative. Since the HR hasn't responded yet, it might mean they are still assessing other candidates and will take a final call sometime in 2 weeks. I guess I am just getting too impatient.